# Call a database table header with a variable inside it

Tags: c#, database, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this page where I update what the user has written in the text fields; the text fields values are then sent to the database.

However the variable names are very similar:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Tracking(MPB machineRecord, string Command)
{
    loadBoards();

    var currentMachine = db.MPBs.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Machine == machineRecord.Machine);

    if (Command == "UpdateRecord")
    {

        currentMachine.Board = machineRecord.Board;
        currentMachine.MachineStatus = machineRecord.MachineStatus;
        currentMachine.Hour1_Goal = machineRecord.Hour1_Goal;
        currentMachine.Hour1_Actual = machineRecord.Hour1_Actual;
        currentMachine.Hour1_Scrap = machineRecord.Hour1_Scrap;
        currentMachine.Hour1_Downtime = machineRecord.Hour1_Downtime;
        currentMachine.Hour1_Rework = machineRecord.Hour1_Rework;
        currentMachine.Hour1_Comments = machineRecord.Hour1_Comments;

        currentMachine.Hour2_Goal = machineRecord.Hour2_Goal;
        currentMachine.Hour2_Actual = machineRecord.Hour2_Actual;
        currentMachine.Hour2_Scrap = machineRecord.Hour2_Scrap;
        currentMachine.Hour2_Downtime = machineRecord.Hour2_Downtime;
        currentMachine.Hour2_Rework = machineRecord.Hour2_Rework;
        currentMachine.Hour2_Comments = machineRecord.Hour2_Comments;

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

This continues on for 8 hours, the database was made beforehand and I am unable to change how it is structured. But as you can see, each `currentMachine.HourX` or `machineRecord.HourX` is there a way I can replace that X with a variable so I can just do a for loop to update all the fields to the database?

Comment: Check out AutoMapper: http://automapper.org/  I think this will solve your problem rather nicely.

Comment: If you are using entity framework, you could use SqlQuery: entity.TableName.SqlQuery(string.Format("UPDATE MPBs SET Hour{0}_Goal = {1} WHERE ID = {2}", 1, 2, 3));